# Images not showing on website

Tags: html, image

So I'm making a website for the first time. I've tried to put some images on it to test via Cyberduck. However, it's not working. 
This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test site</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Test</h1>
<p>Test</p>
<img src=“../img/test.png” />
<img src=“../img/tenor.gif”></img>

</body>
</html>
```

My images are stored in the img folder:
[printscreen directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzJ0Z.png)
I've already checked for case-insensiveness.

I've put the images in the img folder and I can access the images via the path. However, I don't see them (in Chrome) or I see that they are broken(in Safari).

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: use `./` instead of `../` or remove the `../`

Comment: also ensure that your quotes are " and not the smart quotes from mac.

Answer (score 0):

This would have been a comment.
Try running a server in the projects directory.
But possible issues might include:
Incorrect file extention.
Incorrect path. Instead of `".../"` use `"/"`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question came from keja. Thanks a lot!

I apparently used the wrong quotes. Images are working now, so problem solved!